# How to split one into multiple in SQL

Tags: mysql

Hello i'm having trouble splitting this in sql

I use stackoverflow_sample_universal database

My table now looks like this

```
id          tags        
13649012    vb.net::vb.net-2010     
19329707    c++::c::boost::makefile::cmake      
17394734    c#::html::asp.net-mvc-4     
26583319    java::class::casting::classloader       
18021406    ios::objective-c::constraints::autolayout       
20670104    visual-studio-2010::sharepoint::.net-framework-version::multi-
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
id          tags
13649012    vb.net
13649012    vb.net-2010
19329707    c++
19329707    c
19329707    boost
19329707    makefile
19329707    cmake
17394734    c#
17394734    html
17394734    asp.net-mvc-4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Consider using general purpose languages like the very ones in your data (C#, Java, VB, even Python, Perl, PHP, R) that can easily connect to MySQL, read data, and split by the colon characters.

Comment: SQL being a special purpose language is designed for data storage, retrieval, and basic manipulations not dynamic wrangling like this. Otherwise look into MySQL's stored procedures with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 1) AS tags FROM table1 
UNION
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 2),'::',-1) AS tags FROM table1
UNION
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 3),'::',-1) AS tags FROM table1
UNION
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 4),'::',-1) AS tags FROM table1
UNION
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 5),'::',-1) AS tags FROM table1
UNION
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 6),'::',-1) AS tags FROM table1
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Good but this assumes max of 6 colon splits. OP may have 30 in actual data.

Comment: add `UNION
SELECT  id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tags, '::', 7),'::',-1) AS tags FROM table1` and more.. more...:)   I have a only this idea